# apache httpd configuration losing forward slash on permanent redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, httpd.conf

All the questions I've seen on this offer up solutions using a `.htaccess` file. We do not use a `.htaccess` file, we use the Apache `httpd.conf`.

We are trying to redirect to HTTPS but in certain circumstances we lose the forward slash and the redirect fails.

For example, `HTTP://www.test.com/apage.html` redirects correctly to `https://test.new.com/apage.html`.

However, `HTTP://test.com/apage.html` ends up at `https://test.new.comapage.html`, which fails.

Both Virtual Host entries reflect the same settings so I'm puzzled why one works and one does not.

```
<VirtualHost x.x.x.x:80>
    ServerName www.test.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@test.com
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/cgi-bin/
    DocumentRoot /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/www.test.com
    CustomLog logs/new/access_log combined
    ErrorLog logs/new/error_log
    ErrorDocument 404 http://www.test.com/indexm.html
    RedirectMatch permanent ^(.*)$ https://test.new.com$1
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost x.x.x.x:80>
    ServerName test.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@test.com
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/cgi-bin/
    DocumentRoot /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/www.test.com
    CustomLog logs/new/access_log combined
    ErrorLog logs/new/error_log
    ErrorDocument 404 http://www.test.com/indexm.html
    RedirectMatch permanent ^(.*)$ https://test.new.com$1
</VirtualHost>
```

**Updated Virtual Host**

Combined virtual host entry returns the same outcome. "www." works, but leaving it off fails.

```
<VirtualHost x.x.x.x:80>
    ServerName test.com
    ServerAlias www.test.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@test.com
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/cgi-bin/
    DocumentRoot /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/www.test.com
    CustomLog logs/new/access_log combined
    ErrorLog logs/new/error_log
    Redirect 301 / https://test.new.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

> However, `HTTP://test.com/apage.html` ends up at `https://test.new.comapage.html`, which fails.

This shouldn't happen with the config as posted. This malformed redirect would occur if you have a `Redirect` directive like the following, where the trailing slash is omitted on the target.

```
Redirect / https://test.new.com
```

However, the two vHost configs you've posted can be combined (using a `ServerAlias`) and the `RedirectMatch` directive can be simplified to the simpler `Redirect` directive.

For example:

```
<VirtualHost x.x.x.x:80>
    ServerName test.com
    ServerAlias www.test.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@test.com
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/cgi-bin/
    DocumentRoot /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/www.test.com
    CustomLog logs/new/access_log combined
    ErrorLog logs/new/error_log
    Redirect 301 / https://test.new.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

The `Redirect` directive is prefix-matching and copies everything after the match on to the end of the target URL. So, the above redirects *everything* like for like to HTTPS and enforces the trailing slash after the hostname.

The `ErrorDocument 404` directive would seem to be superfluous in your vHost:80 container and would have triggered a 302, suppressing the expected 404 response.

Comment: thanks, I'll give this a go now. The redirect match was an attempt at a fix given on another forum.

Comment: "The redirect match was an attempt at a fix" - What did you have initially? Maybe the issue is elsewhere in your config? Note that 301s are cached persistently, so you will need to ensure that the browser (and any intermediary) caches are cleared before testing. Test with 302 (temporary) redirects to avoid potential caching issues. In fact, change to a 302 and make sure the response code changes in the network traffic to confirm this is the rule that is triggered. @DanJamesPalmer

Comment: The direct line read "Redirect / https://test.new.com/" before I changed it to the redirect match

Comment: I've tried your suggestion and the behavior is the same. I've tested across 4 browsers and some mobile devices. Any other information I can gather?

Comment: `The direct line read "Redirect / test.new.com" before` - Was that _with_ the trailing slash on the target URL? I assume you've restarted Apache? Have you checked the network traffic... is there just 1 redirect, or maybe there is a second+ redirect? When you change the response code from 301 to 302 (as you should to test), do you see this reflected in the network traffic? @DanJamesPalmer